# SQL querying alpha-numerical values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have set of data with all kind of values in a column:

```
XXSE
4032
MX10
3750C
MS073
MSDCC014
```

How can I specify the query in such way that I will get only those values where first two characters are text and last two characters are numerical, while the value is exactly 4 characters long?

Comment: What's DBMS? If you mean version of MSQL, it's 11.0.5623.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `LIKE '[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9]'`

Sample

```
SELECT 1 WHERE 'MX42' LIKE '[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9]'
```

Comment: Very nice. How can we deal in case there would not have been a condition on length of the string? i.e. we want to have 'MSDCC014' as well in our output?

Comment: So you mean any number of characters are allowed in the after first 2 characters and last 2 numbers? Just add a `%` in the middle `LIKE '[A-Z][A-Z]%[0-9][0-9]'`